# How can I do SQL queries that depend on other rows?

Tags: sql

[Disclaimer: I struggle to express my issue; all help welcome]

In my understanding of SQL, relations are mostly focused on retrieving rows. I frequently am confronted with the following issue:

How do I efficiently get all the cases where a row with `val2=Z` is followed by a row with `val2=V`? In other words: how do I express queries that can look a head into following rows to see whether there are **sequences of rows** that I am interested in.

```
id     val1    val2
0      A       Z
1      B       V
2      C       Z
3      D       B
```

## Update

Based on the (helpful) answers, I should be clear about one extra thing: the sequence I could be looking is flexible (it could also be `Z B`) and its length can also vary.

Comment: In this case, I figure a conditional index would work: `select * from tblname as a where val2='z' and (select val2 from tblname as b where b.id > a.id order by b.id limit 1) = 'v'` - this should first check the index for `val2='z'` and then conditionally narrow it down based on the subquery. Although personally I'd do this kind of logic in PHP...

Comment: Note: In SQL, rows have no inherent order.  So there is no "next row", unless you define an order to use to determine what that next row is.

Comment: @RBarryYoung . . . It is reasonable to assume that the `id` column provides this information for this question.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol does a conditional index also work with the update of my question? Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I assumed that as well.

Comment: @Private If you want longer sequences, you would do much better to just get the data and run through it in PHP or whatever else is accessing the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI standard has the `lead()` and `lag()` functions.  If you want both rows in your result set, then do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(val2) over (order by id) as prev_val2,
             lead(val2) over (order by id) as next_val2
      from t
     ) t
where (val2 = 'Z' and next_val2 = 'V') or
      (prev_val2 = 'Z' and next_val2 = 'Z');
```

Note:  I am interpreting "is followed by a row" as being in the next row based on the `id`.  Any alternative interpretation becomes ambiguous when dealing with data like ZVV, ZZV, and so on.

Comment: This is cool (and new to me)! There's one bit in your answer that also keeps me thinking: "If you want both rows in your result set". Indeed, I realize that I will just get all the rows that match this pattern. but they will not group together the rows in the ways they match... Maybe doing this 'getting sequences of rows' is not the best thing. Is there another schema that would fit this type of retrieval better?

Comment: @Private . . . As phrased, I don't find the problem specific enough to suggest a schema different from yours.  Perhaps you can ask another question with sample data along with examples of the questions you have and the result sets you want to get back.

Comment: Thanks. Does your solution also extend when the number of rows is higher than two (for instance: `ZVZ`)?

Comment: @Private . . . Yes, both `lag()` and `lead()` take an offset argument.  The default is 1, so I usually leave that out.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do that with SQL only.

My solution would be to use any language able to connect to SQL database (PHP, C, ...) to get the values from the database, then do any test you want in that language.